# Differentiability of restricted volumes of big divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a subvariety of a smooth projective variety $X$ of dimension $n$. The restricted volume on $V$ of a $\mathbb{Q}$--divisor $D$ on $X$ is defined by 
$$\mathrm{Vol}_{X|V}(D):=\limsup_{k\to \infty}\frac{d!}{k^d}h^0(X|V, kD) $$
where $d=\dim V$ and $h^0(X|V, kD)$ is the dimension of the image of the restriction map 
$$H^0(X, kD)\to H^0(V, kD|_V).$$

It is well known that the volume function $\mathrm{Vol}_X: \mathrm{Big}(X)\to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is a differentiable function in any direction, that is $\mathrm{Vol}_X(D+tE)$ is differentiable at $t=0$ for any big divisor $D$ and effective $E$.

Is the restricted volume function also differentiable, i.e. is $\mathrm{Vol}_{X|V}(D+tE)$ differentiable at $t=0$? Any references or counter examples?

Comment: You have probably already seen this, but Example 4.17 in [Boucksom–Favre–Jonsson](https://doi.org/10.1090/S1056-3911-08-00490-6) says that $X = \operatorname{Bl}_P\mathbf{P}^1$ gives an example where $\operatorname{vol}_{X \mid V}$ is not $\mathcal{C}^1$.

Comment: Thank you for point out this example! Would you mind to rewrite the comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I am reposting [my comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315344/differentiability-of-restricted-volumes-of-big-divisors#comment786826_315344) as an answer. Note that [Boucksom, Favre, and Jonsson](https://doi.org/10.1090/S1056-3911-08-00490-6) only state that $X = \operatorname{Bl}_P\mathbf{P}^2$ gives an example of a restricted volume that is not $\mathcal{C}^1$. We will show that their example also gives an example of a non-differentiable restricted volume.

**Example** (see [[Boucksom–Favre–Jonsson](https://doi.org/10.1090/S1056-3911-08-00490-6), Ex. 4.17])**.** Let $X$ be the blowup of $\mathbf{P}^2$ at a point, and let $h,e \in N^1(X)$ be the class of the pullback of a line and the exceptional class, respectively. We then have the following decomposition of the effective cone of $X$:

$\hskip2.25in$[image: Blowup of P2 at a point]

The positive part $P$ of the Zariski decomposition for a point $\alpha = xh-ye$ is as described in the figure above. By [[Ein–Lazarsfeld–Mustaţă–Nakamaye–Popa](https://doi.org/10.1353/ajm.0.0054), Ex. 2.19], the restricted volume for the class $\alpha = xh-ye$ along a curve $C$ with class $ah-be$ can be computed as
$$\begin{aligned}
  \operatorname{vol}_{X \vert C}(\alpha) &= P(\alpha)\cdot(ah-be)\\
  &= \begin{cases}
    ax-by & \alpha \in \operatorname{Nef}^1(X),\\
    ax & \alpha \in \operatorname{\overline{Eff}}^1(X) \smallsetminus \operatorname{Nef}^1(X).
  \end{cases}
\end{aligned}$$
For $\alpha = h+te$, we have
$$\operatorname{vol}_{X \vert C}(h+te) =
\begin{cases}
  a+bt & t\le0,\\
  a & t\ge0,
\end{cases}$$
which is not differentiable at $t = 0$ if $b \ne 0$.